# How to supress nuget warnings warnings in msbuild/visual studio

Tags: msbuild

I have the following warning from VS2017

> 15>C:\Users\phelan\workspace\weincad.net\WeinCad.Plugin\WeinCad.Plugin.csproj
>   : warning NU1602: FSharpx.Async 1.13.2 does not provide an inclusive
>   lower bound for dependency FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq. An approximate
>   best match of FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq 1.13.0 was resolved.

That is warning **NU1602**

I have added

```
  <PropertyGroup >
    <NoWarn>NU1602</NoWarn>   
  </PropertyGroup>
```

to my **Directory.Build.props** file.

Nuget documentation [claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings) that the nuget warnings will be respected by the NoWarn directives.

> The errors and warnings listed here are available only with
>   PackageReference-based projects and NuGet 4.3.0. NuGet also honors
>   MSBuild properties to suppress warnings or elevate them to errors. For
>   more information, see How to: Suppress Compiler Warnings in the Visual
>   Studio documentation.

but the suppression is not respected. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: Is Directory.Build.props being used by VS at restore time? Try adding the NoWarn property directly to the .csproj file to see if that suppresses the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you are hitting a bug tracked by issue #5740 [NoWarn on a package reference does not apply transitively to its dependencies](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5740) in NuGet repo.

The warning is raised not due to direct project dependency `FSharpx.Async 1.13.2` but by that package dependency `FSharp.Control.AsyncSeq`